# How to install changes to /etc/crontab

Tags: cron

If I want to add lines to my system's /etc/crontab, what do I have to do to get them to take effect?

---

Background:

I'm trying to set up a machine with Ubuntu 13.04 so that it automatically locks/unlocks the monitor during the workday (it's hanging on the wall).

I've done this by adding the following to my /etc/crontab:

```
00 18  * * mon-fri myuser export DISPLAY:=0 && gnome-screensaver-command -a
00 18  * * mon-fri myuser export DISPLAY:=0 && xset dpms force standby
00 08  * * mon-fri myuser export DISPLAY:=0 && gnome-screensaver-command -d
00 08  * * mon-fri myuser export DISPLAY:=0 && xset dpms force on
```

The individual commands work fine, but I'm trying to test the crontab entries by setting the minute/day to the upcoming minute. For example, at 1:26PM I set the first two columns to 27 13 and waited until the next minute rolled around. But the commands don't appear to be getting executed. I also tried running `sudo crontab /etc/crontab`, but it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, 27 01 is 1:27AM (not PM)

Comment: Oops. That was just a typo in my post. I was actually using 27 13 in my file. I've updated the post.

Comment: Upon further debugging, I've determined that running "sudo crontab /etc/crontab" is actually reloading the crontab and my commands are being run. Looks like it's just a problem with the specific commands.

I was able to determine this by adding *echo "test" >> /home/myuser/test.txt &&* to the beginning of the command.

Comment: I just noticed your DISPLAY variable exports are wrong as well - it should be DISPLAY=:0 not DISPLAY:=0 i.e. the value of the DISPLAY variable is :0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further debugging, I've determined that running `sudo crontab /etc/crontab` is actually reloading the crontab and my commands are being run. Looks like it's just a problem with the specific commands. I was able to determine this by adding `echo "test" >> /home/myuser/test.txt &&` to the beginning of the command.

Comment: This overwrites your users crontab with the content of /etc/crontab, which is not good, because the source of your crontab might not be /etc/crontab

Answer (score 0):

First, you likely need to specify a path to all commands.  For example:

```
00 08  * * mon-fri DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/xset dpms force on
```

Alternatively, you can put a PATH line at the top of your crontab file.  See `man 5 crontab`.

Second, the system should send cron output to you by email.  Check it for error messages.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The out-of-the-box PATH in /etc/crontab already includes /usr/bin, though, so I don't think that's the problem.